# Добавить обработчик двойных нажатий

Tags: java, android, click

**OnSwipeTouchListener.java**

В данный код необходимо добавить *двойное нажатие*.

```
package com.twikoffin.oneswipe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }



       @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            boolean result = false;
            try {

                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();

                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

**LevelActivity.java**
А этот код должен *обрабатывать двойное нажатие*, так же, как он и обрабатывает свайпы.

```
myRelativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(LevelActivity.this) {

            public void onSwipeTop() {

                action = "8";
                level();
                pStatus = 0;
                step++;
                ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(circleImage,"rotationX",180);
                anim.setDuration(500);
                anim.start();
                v.vibrate(20);
                if (explosionId != 0)
                    soundPool.play(explosionId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

            }

            public void onSwipeRight() {
                action = "6";
                level();
                pStatus = 0;
                step++;
                objectAnimator();
                v.vibrate(20);
                if (explosionId != 0)
                    soundPool.play(explosionId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);


            }

            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                action = "4";
                level();
                pStatus = 0;
                step++;
                objectAnimator();
                v.vibrate(20);
                if (explosionId != 0)
                    soundPool.play(explosionId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);}
            public void onSwipeBottom() {
                step++;
                action = "2";
                level();
                pStatus = 0;
                ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(circleImage,"rotationX",-180);
                anim.setDuration(500);
                anim.start();
                v.vibrate(20);
                if (explosionId != 0)
                    soundPool.play(explosionId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

            }


        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавляй [OnDoubleTaplistener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html).
Вот твой вопрос на  [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530937/how-to-listen-to-doubletap-on-a-view-in-android)